# Dojo: set default TextBox for typing

Tags: javascript, dojo, focus

One would like the cursor to be set on the search field when page loads. Code:

```
<input class="search-input"
  data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
  data-dojo-attach-point="searchNode"
  data-dojo-attach-event="keyup: searchKeyUpEvent"
  data-dojo-props="
    focused: true,
    placeHolder: 'Search'" />
```

On page load the TextBox widget has a focus frame, but the cursor is not there..

- Is this a bug?
- How does one make sure the cursor is at the search widget?

---

**EDIT:**
I will re-phrase the question: how does one set some TextBox, so when the page loads and user starts typing it will appear in that TextBox by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending a few hours and trying bunch of solutions (none of which worked) I came with the one that actually solves the problem - use `setTimeout()`

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
  _this.searchNode.focusNode.focus();
}, 0);
```

I don't like the idea of using a timer (even a zero-timed one), but this might be pretty much the only solution.

Answer (score 3):

`focused` is documented as a read-only property in `_FocusMixin`; setting it initially won't do what you think it does.

To initially focus the widget, you will need to get a reference to it from JS and call its `focus` method.

Given that you've defined an attach point and attach event, I'll assume this widget is part of another widget's template, in which case you should be able to initially focus it in the templated widget's `startup` method (though depending on how your page/app loads, there may be a better time to do this):

```
startup: function () {
    if (this._started) {
        return;
    }
    this.inherited(arguments);

    this.searchNode.focus();
});
```

(I'd probably suggest not calling the attach point "searchNode", since it's a widget in this case, not a DOM node.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For some reason focus() doesn't work. I have added regular <input id="foo" /> and tried to document.getElementById("foo") on startup().. but nothing happens. Does it make any sense?

Comment: In you example, you should also use this.searchNode.focusNode.focus() (since focusNode will be an <input> element, and JS's focus() should be applied to a dom-element, not a widget instance.

Comment: `focus` is a method defined on dijit TextBox widgets (more specifically, `_FormWidgetMixin`), which does exactly what you suggest (`this.focusNode.focus()`).